# C++ retreive function or scope

Tags: c++, scope

As I could not find any question dealing with this problem: Is there some kind of method that holds the current scope (such as a function for instance), aiming at printing where an exception was thrown (and caught)? I know that, for instance, some real time OSses offer such functionality. Working environment is Windows 7/8, but an OS independent call is preferred. (C++1x is ok!)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Something like [backtrace](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace)?

Comment: I checked the possible duplicate beforehand already, but this introduces a new class. I do not need the stack, first of all, and would be glad about just a function call. backtrace is, asaik, not available on Windows. So this question is not a duplicate...

Comment: I could try the WinAPI solution, however...